# Prolog: Filter a list into a list

Tags: list, filter, prolog

I want to create a filter in Prologue from a list that filters out all elements that match the filter.

```
Example: filter(list, element, result)
?- filter([1,2,3,2,3,1,5],3,X).
X=[3,3]
```

But I have created a filter that so far only outputs true or false.

```
filter([L|Y],X,OUT) :- 
    filter(Y,X,OUT).
```

I don't know how to create a list now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually do not need to implement a filter yourself. There is a filter predicate [**`include/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/3):

```
filter(L, X, R) :-
    include(==(X), L, R).
```

You can also implement this yourself with recursion. Here the base case is an empty list:

```
filter([],_,[]).
```

for the recursive case, you can make an if-then-else expression that depending on whether the condition is satisfied, make a list that is (not) prepended with that element:

```
filter([Y|T], X, R) :-
    (  X == Y
    -> …
    ;  …
    ),
    filter(T, X, S).
```

here you still need to fill in `…` yourself.